# An infinite product for $\arccos \alpha$ similar to Viete's formula for $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometry, infinite-product

The following infinite product is well known:

$ (1) \frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\arccos \alpha} = \frac{\sqrt{2+2\alpha}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\alpha}}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\alpha}}}}{2}...$

For $\alpha \neq 1$

This gives an infinite product for $\arccos \alpha$ similar to Viete's formula for $\pi$.

The question is the following: is there any way to get a similar infinite product for $\cos \alpha$ in terms of $\alpha$ and nested square roots by using some process of inversion applied to formula $(1)$ for $\arccos \alpha$?

If yes, is it always possible to derive a similar representation (infinite series, infinite product, continued fraction, etc.) for a function or its inverse, if we have a representation of one of them?

Comment: Can see an article [here](http://rowan.edu/open/depts/math/osler/New_VW5.pdf)